# Jquery Draggable does not work for dynamic content

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I have been trying to build a CMS where the contents are generated automatically and they must be draggable. For this, I have used Jquery UI to make the elements move to other positions.

The problem is that when I generate content dynamically, the jquery's draggable functionality does not work. I generated some divs dynamically with Jquery and I wish that these divs can be draggable but when I try to do it using jquery the content does not move.

If the content is not generated dynamically (static content), then the draggable works.

This is my Jquery Code:

```
$("#btnAddTextsBlog").click(function() {
    var texts = $("#blog_text").val();
    var content2 = "<div id='text1' class='ui-widget-content' style='float: left; margin-left: 30px; margin-right: 30px; margin-top: 30px; display: block;'><p style='font-size: 18px;'>" + texts + "</p></div>";
    $("#main_col_blog_results").append(content2);
});

$(".ui-widget-content").draggable();
```

HTML CODE:

```
<div class="row" id="main_row_blog_results">
   <div class="col-md-12" id="main_col_blog_results">
   </div>
</div>
```

I want to make the dynamic content of the page be `draggable`, any suggestion of where the error may be? How could the `draggable` dynamic content be made?

Comment: You must re-init draggable on the new items. If you run it once, it will not run again until you script it to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time you add element, initialize draggable again.

```js
$("#btnAddTextsBlog").click(function() {

  var texts = $("#blog_text").val();
  var content2 = "<div id='text1' class='ui-widget-content' style='float: left; margin-left: 30px; margin-right: 30px; margin-top: 30px; display: block;'><p style='font-size: 18px;'>" + texts + "</p></div>";

  $("#main_col_blog_results").append(content2);
  $(".ui-widget-content").draggable(); // initialize again
});


$(".ui-widget-content").draggable();
```

Answer (score 0):

When generate `div` add class `draggable` after append.

```
var content2 = "<div id='text1' class='ui-widget-content draggable' style='float: left; margin-left: 30px; margin-right: 30px; margin-top: 30px; display: block;'><p style='font-size: 18px;'>"+texts+"</p></div>";
```

Or Alternative use `.draggable()` whenever append. Working example below.

```
var content2 = "<div id='text1' class='ui-widget-content draggable' style='float: left; margin-left: 30px; margin-right: 30px; margin-top: 30px; display: block;'><p style='font-size: 18px;'>"+texts+"</p></div>";
```

```js
$("#btnAddTextsBlog").click(function() {
  var texts = 'Test Val';
  var content2 = "<div id='text1' class='ui-widget-content' style='float: left; margin-left: 30px; margin-right: 30px; margin-top: 30px; display: block;'><p style='font-size: 18px;'>" + texts + "</p></div>";

  $("#main_col_blog_results").append(content2).draggable();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id='main_col_blog_results'></div>
<input type='button' id='btnAddTextsBlog' value='Test Button'/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. but it doesn' work. I added the draggable but still doesn't work